# Timelineでオブジェクトの位置を移動する方法

Tags: unity3d

unity初心者です。
Timelineでオブジェクトを移動する時、AnimationTrackからtransformの値を変更することで移動させることができますが、
凸凹した地形を移動する場合や、ジェットコースターで縦に一回転するような動きを作る場合、transformの値を細かく変えていく以外に方法はあるのでしょうか？
Timelineのプレビューで再現できるようにしたいです。
ご教授お願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ジェットコースターで縦に一回転するような動きを作る場合、transformの値を細かく変えていく以外に方法はあるのでしょうか？

Cinemachine の Dolly Track with Cart という機能が使いやすいです。ベジェ曲線を引いて、その上を移動させて以下のような事が出来ます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

上の Scene と Timeline を入れた unitypackage を置いておきます。

- [unitypackage](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lc1egk0o2xtzm4x/DollyTrack.unitypackage?dl=1)

> 凸凹した地形を移動する場合

こちらも Dolly Track with Cart である程度できると思いますが、地形によってはやりにくいですね。例えば階段を降りるカットシーンだったら、早めに足下を画角からはずしてごまかし、足と地形を合わせなければならない手間を削るだろうと思います。